# How to do best organization of install and delete in the same ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I try to figure how I must to construct an ansible playbooks where I can do some action and undo them (I can install or remove same packages; place file or remove this file).

If I create two ansible playbooks: delete.yml and install.yml. There are may be problem's like:
I added to installation someting, but don't change deletion

Example:

install.yml:

```
---
- name: Add x2go repository
  apt_repository: repo='deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu precise main' state=present
  apt_repository: repo='deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu precise main' state=present
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
  tags:
    - remote-access-x2go
- name: Install x2go application
  apt: name=x2goserver update_cache=yes state=present
  apt: name=x2goserver-xsession update_cache=no state=present
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
  tags:
    - remote-access-x2go
```

delete.yml:

```
---
- name: Add x2go repository
  apt_repository: repo='deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu precise main' state=absent
  apt_repository: repo='deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu precise main' state=present
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
  tags:
    - remote-access-x2go
- name: Install x2go application
  apt: name=x2goserver update_cache=yes state=absent
  apt: name=x2goserver-xsession update_cache=no state=absent
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
  tags:
    - remote-access-x2go
```

Comment: Just a note here: you can't use ansible module multiple times within a single ansible task - only single one would be used. This is because task inside ansible playbook is basically associative array so you can't have multiple values for single key there.

Comment: @marbu Don't understand. In ansible 1.4.4 I used multiple times apt module in task.

Comment: @marbu is right, you can't use `apt` or any other module more than once *per task*. One task = one action. In your code above you have multiple `apt` and `apt_repository` actions which won't work. You have to define a separate task for every action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very interesting idea. I have personally never tried the 'undoing' workflow, but I can see the nice things about this idea and would like to use it sometime. Here is what I would do.

1. In my `ansible-role/defaults/main.yml` I would define a variable flag

   ```
   # defaults file for ansible-role
   flag_undo: false
   ```
2. In my `ansible-role/tasks/main.yml` I would have

   ```
   - name: task foo bar
     command: falana dhimaka

   - name: undoing task foo bar
     command: undo falana dhimaka
     when: flag_undo=true
   ```
3. So by default our flag is always false. So when installing things I would us the first command below to run my plays. And to uninstall I would use the second command.

   ```
   ansible-playbook foo-play.yml
   ansible-playbook foo-play.yml --extra-vars "flag_undo=true"
   ```

Comment: it didn't work until the test was `when: flag_undo|bool == true` or `when: flag_undo|bool`

Answer (score 2):

One approach that I use in some cases is to simply have lists of packages that you want installed and lists you want removed, then iterate over each list.  I use this basic method not only for packages but other things as well, like users, groups, etc.  For example, I have a "packages" role that has the following files in it:

vars/main.yml:

```
---
installed_system_packages:
  - telnet
  - screen
  - postfix

latest_system_packages:
 - glibc

removed_packages:
 - sendmail
```

tasks/main.yml:

```
---
- name: Install system packages (latest)
  yum: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items: latest_system_packages

- name: Install system packages
  action: yum pkg={{ item }} state=installed
  with_items: installed_system_packages

- name: Remove unwanted packages
  action: yum pkg={{ item }} state=removed
  with_items: removed_packages
```

This way, if I decide that I no longer want a package like telnet installed I can just move it from `installed_system_packages` to `removed_packages`. Or if I want to ensure I'm running the latest version of screen I would simply move it to the `latest_system_packages` list. Then it's just a matter of re-running the role to have the changes applied.

Comment: My question: If I want undo playbook? I have something to remove/something to install. When I want undo this -> I need install what was deleted and delete what was installed

Comment: In the above example you just put the packages in the appropriate list.  If you decide you no longer need 'screen' then move it to remove_packages and run this role.  If at a later time you decide you need it back then you just move it back to installed_system_packages and run the role again.

Answer (score 0):

Some tasks have the opposite states  "present" and "absent". We can use the terms "deploy" and "destroy" instead:

```yaml
- name: Install Apache httpd
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    name: apache2
    state: "{{ 'present' if target_state == 'deploy' else 'absent' }}"
```

This way, we can control whether to deploy or destroy the Apache httpd server using the target_state variable, like so:

```bash
ansible-playbook apache-httpd.yaml --extra-vars target_state=deploy
or 
ansible-playbook apache-httpd.yaml --extra-vars target_state=destroy
```

If a task does not support these states, or does not support state at all, you can use "when" and create separate blocks or roles to deploy or undo your system.